# Disable specific Symfony routes

Tags: php, symfony

Long story short: I'm setting up a [private Packagist site](https://github.com/composer/packagist) for my company, and I need to disable user registration [users are created by Chef] while still allowing Github OAuth connectivity.

I disabled the general signup page by adding the following un-satisfiable condition to the route in `routing.yml`:

```
fos_user_register:
    resource: '@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml'
    prefix: /register
    condition: "1 == 0"
```

However I've found that if you try to sign in with Github without first connecting your existing account there is a second registration form under `/connect/registration` that are governed by the routes:

```
hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: '@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml'
    prefix:   /connect
```

in `routing.yml`, and:

```
<route id="hwi_oauth_connect_registration" path="/registration/{key}">
    <default key="_controller">HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:registration</default>
</route>
```

Which is in `vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml`.

How can I disable only `/connect/registration` without modifying the `connect.xml` in the vendor folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the content of the file `'@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml'` and paste it in a new `app/config/routing_hwi_connect.xml`.

Disable the route by setting up your custom check in the newly created file:

```
<route id="hwi_oauth_connect_registration" path="/registration/{key}">
    <default key="_controller">HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:registration</default>
    <condition>1 == 0</condition>
</route>
```

In your `routing.yml`, change `hwi_oauth_connect` to:

```
hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "routing_hwi_connect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect
```

And it should return a `404` when someone try to access it.

Also, there is surely better approach to allow/restrict routes, maybe by creating a pre-register method, then look in the [SecurityBundle configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) where you can easily do something good.

Comment: If I remove the route the app gets angry and 500s, but adding `<condition>1 == 0</condition>` to the route gives a friendlier 404. That aside, I'm thinking of dropping in a static file containing "Don't do that, do *this* instead" info with based on [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html) instead of the `1 == 0` conditions.

Comment: Of course, the route is surely used by many controllers and templates for route generation, I will make a quick edit to add your condition (that is a bit strange but useful!) . The template can be a good alternative rather than than a 404.